# How disabled source map and js-file compile with AoT of Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack

I have angular2-webpack-starter.

```
.
├── src
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   │   ├── app.component.scss
│   │   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   │   └── app.module.ts
│   │   ├── main.ts
│   │   ├── polyfills.ts
│   │   └── vendor.ts
├── node_modules
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
├── typedoc.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

When I use

$ ngc -p tsonfig.json

```
.
├── compiled
 └── source
    │       └── auth
    │           ├── app
    │           │   ├── app.component.ngfactory.js
    │           │   ├── app.component.ngfactory.js.map
    │           │   ├── app.component.ngfactory.ts
    │           │   ├── app.component.ngsummary.json
    │           │   ├── app.component.scss.shim.ngstyle.js
    │           │   ├── app.component.scss.shim.ngstyle.js.map
    │           │   ├── app.component.scss.shim.ngstyle.ts
    │           │   ├── app.module.ngfactory.js
    │           │   ├── app.module.ngfactory.js.map
    │           │   ├── app.module.ngfactory.ts
    │           │   └── app.module.ngsummary.json
    │           └── main.ngsummary.json
├── src
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   │   ├── app.component.js
│   │   │   ├── app.component.js.map
│   │   │   ├── app.component.scss
│   │   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   │   ├── app.module.js
│   │   │   ├── app.module.js.map
│   │   │   └── app.module.ts
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   ├── main.js.map
│   │   ├── main.ts
│   │   ├── polyfills.js
│   │   ├── polyfills.js.map
│   │   ├── polyfills.ts
│   │   ├── vendor.js
│   │   ├── vendor.js.map
│   │   └── vendor.ts
├── node_modules
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
├── typedoc.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

Why after generation "compiled" directory does not already deleted unnecessary map/js files of source directory? How make autoremove?

Because, webpack no longer uses these files (map / js) in my directory source

```
$ webpack
```

main.ts

```
/* main */
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../../compiled/source/auth/app/app.module.ngfactory';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

if (process.env.TYPE === 'prod') {
    enableProdMode();
}

export function main(): Promise<any> {
  return platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
}

export function bootstrapDomReady() {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
}

bootstrapDomReady();
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "compiled",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
}
```